# The sum amount from join tables is incorrect

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to get the sum of the admin added into transactions. The transactions is splitted into multiple tables, and now i want to get a total from both tables separately. End up the results i'm getting is ridiculous high. I not sure is it my query multiplied the value somewhere.

```
User::select('user.name as name',
                DB::raw('sum(CASE WHEN current.amount > 0 THEN current.amount END) as current_positive'),
                DB::raw('sum(CASE WHEN current.amount < 0 THEN current.amount END) as current_negative'),
                DB::raw('sum(CASE WHEN cash.amount > 0 THEN cash.amount END) as cash_positive'),
                DB::raw('sum(CASE WHEN cash.amount < 0 THEN cash.amount END) as cash_negative')
                )->leftjoin('current_transaction as current', 'current.created_by', '=', 'user.id')
                ->leftjoin('cash_transaction as cash', 'cash.created_by', '=', 'user.id')
                ->whereBetween('current.created_at', [$start_date->format('Y-m-d'), $end_date->format('Y-m-d')])
                ->whereBetween('cash.created_at', [$start_date->format('Y-m-d'), $end_date->format('Y-m-d')])
                ->where('user.type', 3)
                ->groupBy('user.name')
                ->get();
```

---

### Update

I'm trying with the solution from M Khalid, and the following is the error message:

1. ->mergeBindings($CUT)

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mergeBindings() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

2. ->mergeBindings($CUT->getBindings())

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mergeBindings() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder, array given

3. ->addBinding($CUT)

> ErrorException: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting wrong sum amount because of the left joins and each joined table may have more than one rows per user which makes the sum amount quite higher than the original one, to sort out this issue you need to calculation these sum amounts in indvidual sub clauses and then join these with main somewhat like

```
select users.name as name,cu.*,ca.*
from users
left join (
    select created_by,
    sum(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END) as current_positive,
    sum(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END) as current_negative
    from current_transaction
    where created_at between :start_date and :end_date
    group by created_by
) cu on users.id = cu.created_by
left join (
    select created_by,
    sum(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END) as cash_positive,
    sum(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END) as cash_negative
    from cash_transaction
    where created_at between :start_date and :end_date
    group by created_by
) ca on users.id = ca.created_by
where users.type = 3
```

To do above in laravel is quite complex like for each sub clause get the sql and query builder object and then use them in main query somewhat like below

```
// For current_transaction
$CUT = CurrentTransaction::query()
    ->select('created_by',
              DB::raw('sum(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END) as current_positive'),
              DB::raw('sum(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END) as current_negative')
            )
    ->from('current_transaction')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date->format('Y-m-d'), $end_date->format('Y-m-d')])
    ->groupBy('created_by');
$CUTSql = $CUT->toSql();

// For cash_transaction
$CAT = CashTransaction::query()
    ->select('created_by',
              DB::raw('sum(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END) as cash_positive'),
              DB::raw('sum(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END) as cash_negative')
            )
    ->from('cash_transaction')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date->format('Y-m-d'), $end_date->format('Y-m-d')])
    ->groupBy('created_by');
$CATSql = $CAT->toSql();

// Main query
User::select('user.name as name','cu.*','ca.*')
    ->leftjoin(DB::raw('(' . $CUTSql. ') AS cu'),function($join) use ($CUT) {
            $join->on('user.id', '=', 'cu.created_by');
            /* ->addBinding($CUT->getBindings());*/
    })
    ->leftjoin(DB::raw('(' . $CATSql. ') AS ca'),function($join) use ($CAT) {
            $join->on('user.id', '=', 'ca.created_by');
            /* ->addBinding($CAT->getBindings());  */
    })
    ->where('user.type', 3)
    ->mergeBindings($CUT) /* or try with ->mergeBindings($CUT->getBindings()) */
    ->mergeBindings($CAT) /* or try with ->mergeBindings($CAT->getBindings()) */
    ->get();
```

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid , Thanks for your prompt respond bro. I'm trying with the code and it show my some error for binding. What's the meaning of binding actually? Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::addBinding()

Comment: @1myb according to [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-you-add-a-binding-when-using-dbraw-in-a-join) try the updated answer , may the bindings in join part was removed from newer version, Hope it helps

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, I've updated the questions with the results of different way of bindings. Unfortunately it's not working yet. Thanks

Comment: Did some research, I think because i didn't use Union so cannot use the mergeBindings. I tried to update the code to ->mergeBindings($CUT->getQuery()) and I'm getting empty results

Comment: I'm using raw to solve the problem. raw work perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @1myb Can you also post your solution as answer so that i can also view how exactly you solved the problem and also for future visitors. Glad you solved this issue

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, I was using DB::raw to execute the SQL provided in your solution. Thanks